# Why are marked E-Mails by iPhone's Mail.app not shown in GMail's marked folder?

Tags: iphone, gmail, email, exchange

I have a GMail account (Google Apps with my own domain) hooked up as an exchange account in my iPhone.

**If I mark an E-Mail (as shown in the screenshot) on my iPhone, it is not regonized by the GMail Web Client aka shown in the *marked* folder.**

Do I have to configure something in my iPhone to fix this or is this not possible?

The text in the screenshot is german, but I think it is clear what means what. :-)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think this is possible using the iPhone mail app. Marking an item with the iPhone mail app doesnt 'star' it on Google.

I'd recommend trying the [official Gmail App](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/gmail/id422689480?mt=8) for iPhone and iPad.

Comment: The GMail App improved a lot since the last time I used it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yeah they took it down for a period due to issues, but the latest version works well.